# registering a global template wordpress 6.0

Tags: theme-development, themes

```
  <?php 
    
    /*
    *   Template Name : Amaizing Inner Page 1 Template from me*
    * @package WordPress
    * @subpackage CADENTIC® BUSINESS THEME
    * @since MY BUSINESS THEME 0.0.1
        */
    
    ?>
```

if we would these simple lines in a template file we would use it as a global template but now in WordPress 6.0, there is no such attribute that exists in Gutenberg to select a new page template.  I was following a few articles for this [wordpress doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#common-wordpress-template-files) [clouddera](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/creating-custom-page-template-in-wordpress/) [image: no]

Answer (score 1):

> but now in WordPress 6.0, there is no such attribute that exists in Gutenberg to select a new page template.

This is not true! WP 6.0 did not remove this functionality. In fact in the block editor it is even more prominent and has its own dedicated panel if you scroll up the sidebar:

[image]

If this isn't showing then you should enable it in the block editor settings window:

[image]

Keep in mind that the article you've linked to is talking about *the classic editor*.

The final possibility, is that poor/strange formatting has broken the ability to parse your template header.

E.g. instead of this:

```php
  <?php 
    
    /*
    *   Template Name : Amaizing Inner Page 1 Template from me*
```

Do this:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Amazing Inner Page 1 Template from me*
```

See the official documentation for page templates for details and examples:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use

Comment: with base installation, it was not there. and after installing other plugins it's coming up. but still, those custom build templates did not show up.

Comment: your original question includes lots of misaligned formatting, can you fix that in the templates? Are you sure you didn't turn off the template panel in block settings? _WP 6.0 did not remove this feature._ I've summarised this in my latest edits. Keep in mind that removing this would be a major backwards compatibility break that would have been announced on the official Make WP blog as well as in the fieldguide post

Comment: any other alternative option to register that global template?

Comment: None, this is the only method of registering page templates, it should work, and it works for me on WP 6.0. If you have done it correctly and the UI does not show then the registration is not the problem. Note the formatting issues I mentioned in my answer though, it's more likely that you've turned off the templates panel, or that you have not registered your page template correctly by using the incorrect format